# Spatialite trigger to update a polygon attribute with the sum of a point attribute where points are within a polygon

Tags: triggers, sum, spatialite

Here is my goal:
I have 2 layers in spatialite DB: 
- the layer 'abonnes', a point layer with an attribute 'nbabonnes'
- the layer 'communes', a polygon layer with an attribute 'nbabonnescom'
Each time I add a point 'abonnes', I'd like to update the attribute 'nbaonnescom' with the sum of the values of 'nbabonnes' of all the points abonnes that are within the polygon that contains the new point.
I tried this trigger:

```
CREATE TRIGGER abonnes_nw_updcommunes
AFTER INSERT
ON abonnes
BEGIN
UPDATE communes SET 
    "nbabonnescom" = 
        (
        SELECT SUM(abonnes.nbabonnes)
        FROM abonnes JOIN communes ON
        ( within(abonnes.GEOMETRY, (SELECT communes.GEOMETRY FROM communes, abonnes WHERE ST_Contains(communes.GEOMETRY, NEW.GEOMETRY))))
        )
WHERE within(NEW.GEOMETRY, communes.GEOMETRY);
END;
```

The result is almost correct, but in fact, the result for 'nbabonnescom' is multiplied by the number of 'communes' polygons.
For example, if I should obtain 23, and that I have 5 'communes' polygons, I obtain 115 for nbabonnescom. I don't understand why.

Answer (score 0):

After several tests, I found the right SQL Code to obtain the correct result:

```
CREATE TRIGGER abonnes_nw_updcommunes
AFTER INSERT
ON abonnes
BEGIN
UPDATE communes SET 
    "nbabonnescom" = 
        (
        SELECT SUM(abonnes.nbabonnes)
        FROM abonnes JOIN communes ON
        ( within(abonnes.GEOMETRY,communes.GEOMETRY )) WHERE ST_Contains(communes.GEOMETRY, NEW.GEOMETRY)
        )
WHERE within(NEW.GEOMETRY, communes.GEOMETRY);
END;
```